# Request a tag for "Fallout-board game"

Tags: support, tags

A new board game is out, [Fallout Board Game](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/fallout/) which I think needs a tag. More specifically, I was planning to as a question regarding it, but cannot since there is no tag.